# How do I parse a JSON List in Java whose elements are all named?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON String of the type below:

```
{
  "entry_1" : {
     "value_1":"a",
     "value_2":"b",
     "value_3": [ "c" ],
  },
  "entry_2" : {
     "value_1":"d",
     "value_2":"e",
     "value_3": [ "f" ],
  },

  ...
}
```

The entries `entry_1`, `entry_2`, `entry_...` are weird because it looks like they form a list, but when I try to parse them into a `JSONArray` I get the exception:

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

My code to parse this string is:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(myFile));

for (Object obj : array)
{
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
    
    // Do stuff with jsonObj
}
```

How do I parse this strange JSON?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's not a list, that's an object

Comment: Look at the punctuation, not the names. `{}` means that this is an object. If it were a list (or more accurately an array) then it would be surrounded by `[]`.

Comment: Yes but it IS a listing of items, there are thousands of items, I am not going to get each object by name??

Comment: Part of your confusion is that numbers in the object keys signal that this should almost certainly be an array instead of an object. But when you are parsing the data, you don't have any control over that. You have to parse what is given.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OK but how do I automate the parsing, there are thousands of objects inside that?

Comment: @user5123481566 Exactly the way you are now. Just parse it as a `JSONObject` instead of a `JSONArray`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you. But then how would I iterate over the sub-objects in it?

Comment: @user5123481566 That is a different question than what you posted here. I suggest you look at the API docs for `JSONObject` to figure out that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entries `entry_1`, `entry_2`, `entry_`... are weird because it looks like they form a list, but when I try to parse them into a JSONArray I get the exception:

The names of the keys don't matter here. Since the JSON is surrounded with `{}`, you have an object here, not an array. So you should parse it as an object:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(myFile));
```

With that said, you are correct that an array would be more appropriate here since the keys are just numbered anyway.